# How can I hide a figure but keep its numbering?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I have a document with many figures; I want to print a short version of it with some figures hidden, but I would like that the global numbering of figures remain the same, and that labels still works. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{figure1} shows \ldots

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{figure1.jpg}
    \caption{\label{figure1}}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{figure2} shows \ldots

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{figure2.jpg}
    \caption{\label{figure2}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Then I would like to hide figure 1 from PDF output, but label `figure1` should still work, and the second picture should still be numbered as 2. Is it possible?

I tried with the `comment` environment but it does not work.

Comment: if i correctly understood your question, than adding `%` before `includegraphics` is what you looking for. for example `\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
   % \includegraphics[width=5cm]{figure1.jpg}
    \caption{\label{figure1}}
\end{figure}`

Comment: Yes, but my goal is to have one version of my document, and by switching one option in the preamble, it would turn on/off some less important figures.

Comment: @JPG: Do you *always* have `\label` inside `\caption`?

Comment: @Werner: Yes, always. And sometimes I have subfigures with labels for each one.

Comment: What should happen to the `\caption`? Should it still go to the LoF?

Comment: @Skillmon: for me it is not important, I don't print the LoF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be best to put these possibly-invisible figures inside their own environment. That way you can control how they are managed. Below I suggest something like `conditionalfigure` together with `\hidefigurestrue` to hide them, or `\hidefiguresfalse` (the default) to keep them in the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,environ}

\newsavebox{\figsavebox}% Box to capture figure content

\newif\ifhidefigures % Conditional to hide figures or keep them in the document

\NewEnviron{conditionalfigure}[1][ht]{%
  \ifhidefigures
    % Hide this figure
    \let\oldlabel\label
    \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\gdef\labelname{##1}}% Store label name
    \renewcommand{\caption}[1]{##1}% Make \caption just print its argument
    \begin{lrbox}{\figsavebox}
      \BODY % Capture enture figure body
    \end{lrbox}
    \refstepcounter{figure}\oldlabel{\labelname}% Step counter with reference and mark with label
  \else
    % Traditional figure environment
    \begin{figure}[#1]
      \BODY
    \end{figure}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\hidefigurestrue % Remove conditional figures from document
%\hidefiguresfalse % Keep conditional figures in document (default)

Figure \ref{figure1} shows \ldots

\begin{conditionalfigure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{\label{figure1}}
\end{conditionalfigure}

Figure \ref{figure2} shows \ldots

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\label{figure2}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Capturing the entire `conditionalfigure` contents ensures that it doesn't impede with the placement of floats within the document, otherwise the "invisible" float may still take up space above/below it.

Comment: It works well and is easy to implement. Thanks.

Comment: Why `\gdef` the `\labelname`? Wouldn't a `\def` be enough in case of `\NewEnviron`?

Comment: @Skillmon: Within the `lrbox` environment where `\label` is executed the first time, a `\def` would render `\labelname` undefined when using `\oldlabel{\labelname}`. `\gdef` makes it available for use outside of the `lrbox` group.

Comment: @Werner forgot about the `lrbox`.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for? Using `resizebox` and `minipage` you can make the `includegraphics` and `caption` have zero height.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{figure1} shows \ldots

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \resizebox{!}{0cm}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \label{figure1}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{figure2} shows \ldots

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
    \label{figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\resizebox`? You could as well just put the stuff in `\box0` and never output it.

Comment: Yes, your output is what I want, but it doesn't work on my computer, figure 1 is still visible with bad alignment.

Comment: @Skillmon I've not heard of `\box0` before. How would you use it in this context?

Comment: I managed to obtain your output by changing `\resizebox{!}{0cm}` to `\resizebox{!}{0.000001cm}`; strange that it doesn't work with `0cm`...

Comment: Something like `\setbox0\hbox{...}`. The 0 box register is often used for temporary stuff (e.g. by `\smash` and the like). Stuff which is typed in a `\setbox` is fully evaluated and stored in the specified box register, but not output (you can then output it by `\unhbox` in case of a `\hbox`, or `\unvbox` for `\vbox`; there are other methods of outputting them, the simplest being `\box`, all of the aforementioned require you to specify a box register, e.g. 0 or the name of a `\newbox` or `\newsavebox`, the latter being the LaTeX macro, the former TeX).

Comment: And the LaTeX macro for `\setbox0\hbox{...}` would be `\sbox{0}{..}` or `\savebox{0}{..}`. The LaTeX macros include the colour group, so might be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

If the caption should still produce an entry in the LoF, one could use the following (with kind help of @DavidCarlisle on the `\immediate\write` part). The only problem is that if two floats happen to be on the same page and one of them is hidden, the order of the entries in the LoF might get swapped.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\newif\ifhidefigures

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{conditionalfigure}[1][]
  {%
    \ifhidefigures
      \let\zz\write
      \protected\def\write{\immediate\zz}%
      \def\conditionalfigure@start
        {%
          \def\@captype{figure}\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\color@setgroup
        }%
      \def\conditionalfigure@finish
        {%
          \color@endgroup\egroup
        }%
    \else
      \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \def\conditionalfigure@start
          {\begin{figure}}%
      \else
        \def\conditionalfigure@start
          {\begin{figure}[#1]}%
      \fi
      \def\conditionalfigure@finish
        {\end{figure}}%
    \fi
    \conditionalfigure@start
  }
  {%
    \conditionalfigure@finish
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
Figure \ref{figure1} shows \ldots

\begin{conditionalfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Figure 1\label{figure1}}
\end{conditionalfigure}

Figure \ref{figure2} shows \ldots

\hidefigurestrue
\begin{conditionalfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Figure 2\label{figure2}}
\end{conditionalfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Redefine `\includegraphics`

To hide all figures, add the following line after declaring packages (i.e. after `usepackage` commands). Here you redefine `\includegraphics` to do nothing instead of showing the figures.

```latex
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{}
```