# How to remove figures and tables from a document but keep references to them in the text?

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf

I'm working with `ascelike-new` journal template ([located here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-preparing-your-submission-to-the-american-society-of-civil-engineers-asce/pbwcqsvndpty)). The editor asked me to remove figures from the submitted pdf. Since the journal uses an online system to compile the uploaded tex files, and I cannot manually delete the pages with the figures. I tried many existing solutions (examples [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448521/how-can-i-hide-a-figure-but-keep-its-numbering) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452887/remove-figures-but-keep-references-to-image)) and was unsuccessful (the tried solutions either put a frame or hide the figure and its text references).

Is there any way I can remove the figures and list of figures and keep references in the text?

Comment: do you want to remove only the graphics or also the captions?

Comment: Graphics and the captions

Comment: The editor asked me to supply a word document with 'list of figures' and pdfs of figures separately.

Comment: you could try the endfloat package and then split the pdf in two parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way I can remove the figures and [the] list of figures and keep [cross-]references in the text?

Let's assume that a representative `figure` environment looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Stuff}
\label{fig:stuff}
\includegraphics[...]{...}
\end{figure}
```

and that it is cross-referenced elsewhere in the document via commands such as `\ref{fig:stuff}`.

If you comment out (or delete) this `figure` code block and insert something like

```
\refstepcounter{figure}
\label{fig:stuff}
```

in its place, you can keep using `\ref{fig:stuff}` to create correctly-numbered cross-references, even though no `figure` environment is created and no entry will be placed in the List of Figures (since no `\caption` directive was run).

And, since you no longer want to create a List of Figures (which would be empty anyway, as all `\caption` commands are gone), be sure to also comment out (or delete) the `\listoffigures` command.